# Online Store accepts Paypal in US$ & Ships to Australia

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation

I'm hoping to use PayPal to purchase a new DSLR. I'd like to pay in USD as that's the currency I have funds in my PayPal account in, but i need it shipped to Australia.

Does anybody know of any stores that might do this?

Also, wondering how Canon's international warranty would work if i bought it from a country i'm not residing in? I'll be travelling alot anyway, so assumedly i'm covered wherever in the world i am..?

Comment: You may want to look more at insurance than for warranty with the international travel.  I don't have much experience with it, but my insurance broker assures me that they cover my camera wherever I go.  So even if Nikon is not going to handle it, the insurance company says they will.

Comment: Before you do this, make sure you know how much customs will charge you to import the camera. You could be in for a nasty surprise...

Comment: Yeah i'll definitely get travel insurance - its the safest option for sure. I"ve looked at canon's warranty statement and it seems they'll do repairs internationally provided you have the local purchase receipt.  Regarding customs, yes i've already emailed my customs agent for information about what i'm likely to get stung, but chances are i'll try to buy locally as the price difference isn't much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly eBay is probably your best option - there are many reliable sellers of camera gear.

Comment: Yeah... I just got my new Canon 5D Mark II from ebay purchase... paid on Thursday, received (in Australia, from a US store) on monday.  Pretty damn happy with that!

Answer (score 1):

[Newegg](http://newegg.com) will accept PayPal and ship to the confirmed address in your PayPal account. Being a self-centered American, I've only done that for US addresses - don't know if they'd ship to a confirmed address abroad.

PayPal will also create a debit card for you. Perhaps that's worth a try. In this case, the buyer won't even know it's PayPal.

A third option is that you can indeed use the USD in your PayPal account to pay someone in AUD. I've done this successfully (with Euros, I believe). There is an extra fee to do this, though I don't recall if it's reasonable.

Finally, you could have a US seller ship to a US-based parcel forwarder who sends the item on to you.

Regarding the international warranty, I don't know for Canon, but for Nikon is suspect the answer is no, and they might not even look at it out of warranty.

Comment: Thanks Reid... I'm 99% sure that Newegg won't even ship international.  I've wanted to buy RAM from them before but no go. I can purchase from a local seller that will accept PayPal, just not sure if i can use my US dollars in my paypal account to pay an Australian seller.  Guess i'll just have to try it out and see, unless somebody else here knows?

Comment: You're correct on Newegg unfortunately. However you can pay in any supported currency; PayPal will just charge you a fee for the privilege. You could also use a parcel forwarder. (Answer updated.)